# how to use dataclass inside dictionary?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable

@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    first: str
    second: str
    func: Callable


def some_func():
    return 'hello_world'

def some_func2():
    return 'hello_world2'


OPTIONS = {
    MyDataClass('my_arg', 'my_new_arg', some_func),
    MyDataClass('my_arg2', 'my_new_arg2', some_func2)
}

for arg1, arg2, func in OPTIONS.items():
    do_work(arg1, arg2, func, ...)
```

When executing it I get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'MyDataClass'
```

I'm not really sure what is the issue. my goal is to be able to send the values of OPTIONS to `do_work`. Probably OPTIONS shouldn't be a dict but I'm not sure what type would be suitable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a [dictionary (`{k1: v1, k2: v2}`)](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), that's [a set (`{v1, v2}`)](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Set entries (and dictionary keys for that matter) need to be hashable.

Dataclass instances aren't hashable by default since they're mutable by default.

You'll need to set [`frozen=True` in the `@dataclass` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) to make them immutable and thus hashable.

Additionally, you can't just unpack a `dataclass` like that, you'll need to access the properties.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyDataClass:
    first: str
    second: str
    func: Callable


def some_func():
    return 'hello_world'


def some_func2():
    return 'hello_world2'


def do_work(dc):
    print(dc.first, dc.second, dc.func)


OPTIONS = {
    MyDataClass('my_arg', 'my_new_arg', some_func),
    MyDataClass('my_arg2', 'my_new_arg2', some_func2)
}

for dc in OPTIONS:
    do_work(dc)
```

This prints out

```
my_arg2 my_new_arg2 <function some_func2 at 0x10fb12280>
my_arg my_new_arg <function some_func at 0x10fa48b80>
```